# Bloch Electron velocity at Brillouin Zone edge

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, symmetry, crystals

Ashcroft and Mermin in their discussion on the energy levels near a single Bragg plane (Chapter 9: Electrons in a weak periodic potential) mentions the following while calculating the velocity near the Bragg Plane:

> ... Since the gradient is perpendicular to the surfaces on which the
>   function is constant, the constant-energy surfaces at the Bragg plane
>   are perpendicular to the plane.

and then in the corresponding footnote:

> This result is often, but not always true even when the periodic potential is not weak, because the Bragg planes occupy positions of fairly high symmetry.

Can anyone please explain the footnote with examples?

Comment: What part of the footnote do you want expanded on? How a not-weak potential could make things more difficult and less symmetric? How high symmetry positions might be messed with less than low symmetry positions? Consider what is shown in Fig. 9.6 a few pages later, and replace the small deviation of the Bragg surface with a much larger deviation.

Comment: I cannot understand why the Bragg planes occupying positions of fairly high symmetry will mess with the constant energy surfaces being perpendicular to the Bragg planes. 
I don't think Fig 9.6 clears up that issue because the constant energy surfaces intersecting the Bragg plane are reconstructing themselves to be perpendicular to the Bragg plane.

Comment: See Chapter 15 for Fermi surfaces of some real metals.